# Install mysql-server in ubuntu 16.10 - No Window to set root passowrd during installation process!

Tags: package-management, password, mysql

I am trying to install mysql-server in ubuntu 16.10. I have no problems during installation:

`~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libaec0 ....
 ....
This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.17, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
Setting up mysql-server (5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.10.1) ...`

But during the installation process, the usual window to put password does not appear.

So, I tried to enter with no password and does not work:

`~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Also I tried to configure password with:
`sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation`

... without success (It let me to change password... but does not work when I try to enter in..)

Any Ideas?! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [following link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04) suggest that after installing mysql using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

You should execute the following script:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

This will prompt you for the root password you created in previous step.

In order to check the mysql server, you can try connecting to the database using the mysqladmin tool, which is a client that lets you run administrative commands. For example, this command says to connect to MySQL as root (-u root), prompt for a password (-p), and return the version.

```
mysqladmin -p -u root version
```

For more info please review [the instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: thanks in any case! (usefull information to know about mysqladmin)

Comment: I just close this thread. For anyone with the same problem : sudo mysql -u root -p

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Yaron by your answer and time. But I finally found the solution. I just post this here, because maybe it could help to other people.

When I just run :
  `sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation`

It works fine, but in order to connect to mysql:
   `mysql -u root -p`

Does not work... instead it is required to launch mysql as admin user :
   `sudo mysql -u root -p`